# The words of the first Muslims about the beginningless existence of Allah

Tags: allah, islamic-philosophy, islamic-scholar, salafi

My question is this.

Did the Companions of the Prophet (ﷺ) or the first three generations of scholars (salaf) use the expression "lam yazal" in order to express the idea of the beginningless (eternal) existence of Allah?

Did they use any other words and expressions for the same purpose (such as "Al-Awwal" or "As-Samad")?

The fact is that most often I find discussion of this topic among later generations, after the appearance of philosophy and kalam in Muslim society.

This question was raised by the Mu'tazilites, and later by the Ash'aris, but what about the very first Muslims?

Looking for an answer to the question so far I've only found this:

> (And He is Who created the heavens and the earth in six Days) six days
> of the beginning of this world: each day the equivalent of one
> thousand years, the first day being Sunday and the last Friday (and
> His Throne) before the creation of the heavens and earth (was upon the
> water) and **Allah was before the Throne and before water** … (Tanwîr
> al-Miqbâs min Tafsîr Ibn 'Abbâs)

However, I do not know whether this is authentic from ibn Abbas, and whether it refers to this topic or not.

If I am not mistaken, it is indicated here that Ad-Darimi used this expression ("lam yazal"):

https://books.google.ru/books?id=KiiPDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=Allah+lam+yazal&source=bl&ots=v6MuZqftBl&sig=ACfU3U1XpnaV4yhT72S6Cn3rr97wLk2g0Q&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj60vC y8er-AhWxl4sKHX1CC40Q6AF6BAgjEAM#v=onepage&q=Allah%20lam%20yazal&f= false

But examples and evidence were not provided.

Comment: I doubt that you are expected to find so. Majority of early companions were not interested in philosophical implications of a religion.

Comment: I do not mean philosophy, but the discussion of this issue within the framework of religion. After all, for example, the falsity of polytheism could also be discussed both within the framework of religious texts and through rational arguments.